# Cordova Phonegap: Build for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to create an example app in PhoneGap and Cordova.

I have an example Hello World, and I want to build for iOS (For Android it works just fine).

I have added the platform, but when I run `cordova build ios`, I get:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/ENM.app ENM/Images.xcassets
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/pablo/Documents/po/enm/ENM/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,ENM.xcodeproj,-target,ENM,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/pablo/Documents/po/enm/ENM/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/pablo/Documents/po/enm/ENM/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I saw several questions like this, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: Just a guess: I believe Images.xxassets is related to icons and splash screens. Have you checked all references to icons ans splash images in config.xml?